# Error when build react native for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library'

Tags: windows, react-native

I'm new react-native developer. When i run react native in windows with "react-native run-android", it return error :

> Starting JS server...
>   Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
>   Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library **FAILED**
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library'.
>     Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\23.0.1\support-v4-23.0.1.aar'.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 15 mins 33.768 secs

Can you help me fix this problem? thank!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and it turns out it's got to do with the google play-services-analytics version.
and by adding the following code to the build.gradle file I was able to get rid of the error.

```
compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0"){
force = true
}
```

add it at the top of the dependencies curly braces.
so that it looks like this.
    dependencies { compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-    analytics:8.3.0"){
    force = true
    }
//the rest of the dependencies follow
Go t the page below for a better and more detailed explanation
https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/issues/31